# Radio button's circle to appear in the left

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is it possible to make the Radio-button to appear it's "circle" thingy on the left-side and not the right-side like it's default.

[image: radio-button circle to the left]

- the default will bring the circle to the right-side
- I would like to have it on the left-side

  ```
      option1 = Radiobutton(top_frame, variable=radio_var, text="option 1", font=["arial", 13], value="1")
  option1.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E)
  ```

**Edit:**
Whatever Default side the circle appear, wither it's on the left or Right, how if possible can I change it's place to the opposite side?

Comment: Have you intentionally reversed the concepts of *left* and *right* in this question?

Comment: the default circle did appear right side of the radio. if possible I want it to appear left-side of it.

Comment: I've never seen the circle appear on the right. When I run your code and add the missing bits to make it work, the circle appears on the left.

Comment: I'm confuse as to what is Right, Left, and Wrong ;). Let's assume that the "Circle" is on the Left, how can I make it move to the other side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to create a radio button with no text and position a label widget to the left of it. As far as I know there is no option within the radio button widget for your purposes.

```
from tkinter import*

master = Tk()
var = IntVar()
Label(master, text = "label widget").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(master, text = "", variable = var, value = 1).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)
mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: just to confirm is there no other way of doing this? to do this I have to change the grid's of other widgets. and probably need to use Frame to isolate them, T_T

Comment: After a bit more of research it looks like if you use ttk, you can edit the “style” of the button. See this answer here for how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551294/how-can-i-move-the-text-label-of-a-radiobutton-below-the-button-in-python-tkinte